# Cannot Export and Import Flow that depends upon a Custom Connector

Tags: power-automate, dataverse, power-automate-custom-connector

I have a Dataverse solution containing a single Cloud Flow. Some of the flow shapes make use of a Custom Connector. I have three Dataverse environments: Dev, Test and Prod. The cloud flow is developed in Dev, then the solution is exported as a managed solution to be imported to Test and Prod. The export-import process is complicated by the fact that the Custom Connector that the Cloud Flow uses has a different ID in each environment, so if I simply import the flow to Test/Prod I receive an error telling me that:

`Could not find API 'shared_connector_name-5f7ac9690531491ae8-5f4cc0323bfdfa5e9b'`

When I first developed the process last year I found that I could unzip the managed solution and edit the xml for the cloud flow to replace the ID of the Custom Connector before importing the modified solution to Test/Prod. This worked OK but it felt a little dodgy.

I've just made some changes to the Cloud Flow in the Dev environment. Flow has forced me to replace the Connectors used by the Flow with Connector References which have also been added to the solution. I have tried to carry out the process of export, edit the workflow xml, import to Test but this has not worked. I still receive the `Could not find API 'shared_connector_name-5f7ac9690531491ae8-5f4cc0323bfdfa5e9b'` error even though I have replaced all occurrences of *shared_connector_name-5f7ac9690531491ae8-5f4cc0323bfdfa5e9b* in the xml.

I thought I could get around this by replacing the Custom Connector in each environment with one that has been added to a solution (so that it would have the same ID in each environment) but there is a [known issue with Custom Connectors in Solutions](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Cannot-share-Custom-Connectors-or-Connections/td-p/489664) which prevents them from being shared with other users which makes this useless for me (I have to be able to share the development work with other users).

I'm considering dropping the multiple environments altogether but that will make it much harder to "deploy" the Flow by any process except manually copying individual changes which will be extremely error prone .

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that custom connectors are not only referenced in the workflow xml file in the managed solution *but also in* the `customizations.xml`. Once I updated the references in both files I was able to import the solution successfully.